# Google search Result extraction python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have tried to extract google search results using beautiful soup.
But the extracted urls are in this form:

```
/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/PMOIndia/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiU89Xr_MjwAhUAHLkGHfl3AFI4KBAWMAF6BAgIEAE&usg=AOvVaw3WXSVzoiXCQOliyGZxjkSd
```

i want only the 'https://www.facebook.com/PMOIndia/' part of the url.

The code that i have used is

```
    page="https://www.google.com/search?q="+str(query)+"&sxsrf=ALeKk01EudGSzSmaU8dDy9kgRgdOqE_UMQ:1620987283855&ei=k02eYLW6M7ud4-EPvNyM0Ag&start="+str(page)+"&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj1z_SZ-MjwAhW7zjgGHTwuA4oQ8tMDegQIARA3&biw=1536&bih=722"
driver = requests.get(page) 
sleep(randint(2,10))
soup= BeautifulSoup(driver.text, 'html.parser')
for path in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'kCrYT'}):
    x =path.find('a')
    try:
        urls.append(x.get('href'))
    except AttributeError :
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
url = "/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/PMOIndia/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiU89Xr_MjwAhUAHLkGHfl3AFI4KBAWMAF6BAgIEAE&usg=AOvVaw3WXSVzoiXCQOliyGZxjkSd
"
new_url = "/".join(url[7:].split("/",4)[:4])+"/"
```